# Problems with Set Function

Tags: measure-theory, average, means, outer-measure, amenability

(Questions are at the bottom of the post. I’ve added two more doubts since the recent answer.)

## Introduction

Consider $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ where $A\subseteq[a,b]$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $S$ is a fixed subset of $A$.

Before mentioning my set function, it is important to know I need it to compute my average. The average should satisfy the following

1. Positivity: If $f>0$, $\operatorname{average}(A,f)>0$.
2. Linearity: $\operatorname{average}(A,f+g)=\operatorname{average}(A,f)+\operatorname{average}(A,g)$, and $\operatorname{average}(A,cf(x))$ is $c \times\text{average}(A,f(x))$.
3. As $f\to\text{constant function}$, $\operatorname{average}(A,f)\to\text{constant}$
4. The $\operatorname{average}{(A,f)}$ should give a defined, unique value when $f$ is defined on a measurable set. Take for example functions defined on Lebesgue measurable sets.
5. The average of $f$ should satisfy $\inf f \le \operatorname{average} (A,f) \le \sup f$ when $f$ is defined on measurable sets.

The Average defined by the Lebesgue Measure and Integral does not fit all the requirements. If $\lambda(A)$ is the Lebesgue Measure of $A$ and $\lambda(A)=0$, then the average of $f$ is undefined breaking rules 4 and 5. I wish to define an average that matches all the rules and gives the following.

- When $\lambda(A)>0$, the average should be the Lebesgue Average.
- When $A$ is finite the average of $f$ should be

$$\frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{x\in A}f(x)$$

- When $A$ is infinite and $\lambda(A)=0$, divide $[a,b]$ into $r$ equal sub-intervals. Take the average of $f$ over the infimum of all sub-intervals that meet $A$. Call this the lower average. Take the average of $f$ over the supremum of all sub-intervals that meet $A$. Call this the upper average. As $r\to\infty$, if the lower and upper average meet at the same value, call this the total average. When the total average is defined it should equal the average I want to define.
- There are cases of $f$ where neither of these averages can give a defined value. Rather we generalize these definitions into my average and see that supports rules 4. and 5.

The problem may not be well-defined since an average may be unable to exist on all zero Lebesgue Measure sets.

However, before working on my average, I would like to work on my set function which I shall use to compute my average.

Note the set function I am defining may **not** be a measure. It could be finitely additive but give positive values for sets with zero Lebesgue measure.

## Definition of Outer Set Function $\mu^{*}(c,S)$

If we define the following:

- $I=[a,b]$
- $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$
- $\left(I_k\right)_{k=1}^{m}$ are $m$ open sub-intervals of $I$
- $\ell(I)=b-a$ is the length of $I$
- $\ell(I_k)=c\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ is the length of $I_k$ for $k=1,...,m$

$$\Omega(S\cap I_k)=\begin{cases} 
0 & S\cap I_k \ \text{is countable}\\
1 & S\cap I_k \ \text{is uncountable} \\ 
\end{cases}$$

then $\mu^{*}(c,S)$ is the outer piece-wise set function defined as

\begin{align*}
& \mu^{*}(c,S)=  \begin{cases}\inf\limits_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}c\ \Omega\left(S\cap I_{k}\right): S\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m}I_{k}\right\} & A \ \text{is uncountable}\\
\inf\limits_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}c : S\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m}I_{k} \right\} & A \ \text{is countable}\\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

### Explanation of $\mu^{*}(c,S)$

(Skip if you understand my definition)

The parameter $c$ must remain a variable throughout the computation of $\mu^{*}(c,S)$. When $A$ is uncountable, $\mu^{*}(c,S)$ should equal $cm^{\prime}_{\text{min}}$, where $m^{\prime}_{\text{min}}$ is the minimum number of $I_k$ that cover $S$ for $k$ where $S\cap I_k$ is uncountable. The reason we set some $I_k$ to lengths zero is that countable subsets of $A$, such as countable $S\cap I_k$, are regarded to be as small as the null set compared to the uncountable set. Hence we "prevent" corresponding $I_k$ from covering this part of $S$ by setting their "lengths" to zero instead of $c$.

When $A$ is countable $\mu^{*}(c,S)$ should equal $cm_{\text{min}}$ where $m_{\text{min}}$ is the minimum number of $I_k$ that can cover $S$. Here $S\cap I_k$ can be countable (instead of uncountable). When $A$ is countable, we do not set the length of any $I_k$ to be zero, since countable subsets of countable $A$, should be covered by $I_k$ such that the total length of $I_k$ should have a positive proportional value to $\mu^{*}(c,A)$.

### Inner Set Function $\mu_{*}(c,S)$ and Total Set Function $\mu(c,S)$ where $\mu(c,S)=\mu^{*}(c,S)=\mu_{*}(c,S)$

The inner set function should be

$$\mu_{*}(c,S)=\mu^{*}(c,A)-\mu^{*}(c,A\setminus S)$$

Making the total set function $\mu(c,S)$ defined for values of $c$ where,

$$\mu(c,S)=\mu^{*}(c,S)=\mu_{*}(c,S)$$

I added this so the total set function would be as rigorous as the Lebesgue Measure. I'm not sure whether this is necessary.

The problem is for most values of $c$, $\mu^{*}(c,S)\neq \mu_{*}(c,S)$, so to fix this I set the limit as $c\to 0$.

$$\lim_{c\to 0}\mu(c,S)=\lim_{c\to 0}\mu^{*}(c,S)=\lim_{c\to 0}\mu_{*}(c,S)$$

## Questions

What is $\lim\limits_{c\to 0}\mu(c,\mathbb{Q})$, $\lim\limits_{c\to 0}\mu(c,\ln(\mathbb{Q}_{>0}))$, and $\lim\limits_{c\to 0}\mu(c,\mathbb{Q}\cup\ln(\mathbb{Q}_{>0}))$, where $A=\mathbb{Q}\cup\ln(\mathbb{Q}_{>0})$? My guess is all the answers would be $\lim\limits_{c\to 0}c\left\lceil\frac{b-a}{c}\right\rceil$ since they are countable and dense in $[a,b]$. If I am correct, here is the problem...

If my set function is finitely additive:

$$\lim_{c\to 0}\mu(c,\mathbb{Q}\cup\ln(\mathbb{Q}_{>0}))=\lim_{c\to 0}\left(\mu(c,\mathbb{Q})+\mu(c,\ln(\mathbb{Q}_{>0}))\right)=2(b-a)$$

However, $\lim\limits_{c\to 0}\mu(c,\mathbb{Q}\cup\ln(\mathbb{Q}_{>0}))=\lim\limits_{c\to 0}c\left\lceil\frac{b-a}{c}\right\rceil=b-a$

The finite additivity on my set function doesn't give this, hence either my calculations are wrong or my set function is not finitely additive. Which is true? What should be $\mu^{*}(c,\mathbb{Q})$ and $\mu^{*}(c,\ln(\mathbb{Q}_{>0}))$ instead?

**Edit:** According to a recent answer, the set function is not well-defined for this specific case. Here are a few more things I need resolved.

1. When $A=[a,b]$, does my set function of $S$ equal the Lebesgue measure of $S$.
2. If $A=\mathbb{Q}$ could we solve $\lim_{c\to 0} \mu(c,S)$ by doing the following: Take elements of $S$ that have $n$ decimal places. Take $\lim\limits_{c\to 0}\mu$ of these elements as $n\to\infty$. If we cannot do this, how can we change my definition of $\lim\limits_{c\to 0}\mu(c,S)$ so this is possible.

Comment: Point 4. is not clear for me. Do you mean average should satisfy  some restriction property?

Comment: @Vincent The average should give a single defined value for functions defined on lebesgue measurable sets.

Comment: Wouldn't the following 'stupid' construction satisfy your conditions? If either $\lambda(A)>0$, $A$ is finite or the lower average coincides with the upper average on $A$, define the average as you mentioned. Otherwise, choose an arbitrary point  $a\in A$ and for $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$, we let $average(f)=f(a)$.

Comment: @Vincent It would satisfy my conditions but the construction would be neither “natural”, nor useful, if neither $\lambda(A)>0$, $A$ is finite, nor the upper and lower upper sum converge.

Comment: This comment is about your definition of "average". What maybe can help you is to introduce a second argument, so that your average function is something like: $\text{average}(A,f)$.

Comment: @FormulaWriter Do you understand my set function?

Comment: @FormulaWriter $f$ depends on $A$ and the $\text{average}$ depends on $f$. Perhaps a second argument is uncecessary.

Comment: Is the infimum over all possible combinations of subintervals? Or just subintervals where each subinterval has length $c$? This is not clear to me...

Comment: @supinf The infimum is over sub-intervals where each sub-interval has length $c$. In other words, I am minimizing over the number of sub-intervals; however, I want my set function to be finitely additive.  How do I formally define this?

Comment: A second argument can allow you to define $ \text{average}(A,f):=\frac{1}{\mu_A(A)}\int_{A}f(x) \ d\mu_A (x)$ where $\mu_A $ is a measure on $A$ which you deem more natural for $A$ than Lebesgue measure and which satisfies $\mu_A(A)>0$. For example, you could work with counting measures or Hausdorff measures.

Comment: @FormulaWriter Thank You, but I first need to understand my set function and apply it to my definition of average. Currently I’m trying to figure whether it is finitely additive. See my question at the bottom.

Comment: When you type `\text{average}` instead of `\operatorname{average}` then you don't get proper spacing in things like $5\operatorname{average} (f).$ Instead you see $5\text{average}(f).$ That does _not_ just mean some space is added: rather, the amount of space to the left and right depends on the context. In an actual LaTeX document, you can put `\newcommand{\a}{\operatorname{aveerage}}` before the `\begin{document}` and then in the body of the thing just write `\a` every time. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

> What is $\lim\limits_{c\to 0}\mu(c,\mathbb{Q})$, $\lim\limits_{c\to 0}\mu(c,\ln(\mathbb{Q}_{>0}))$, and $\lim\limits_{c\to 0}\mu(c,\mathbb{Q}\cup\ln(\mathbb{Q}_{>0}))$, where $A=\mathbb{Q}\cup\ln(\mathbb{Q}_{>0})$? My guess is all the answers would be $\lim\limits_{c\to 0}c\left\lceil\frac{b-a}{c}\right\rceil$

Your guess is only partially correct.
If we set $S_1:=\mathbb Q$, $S_2:=\ln\mathbb Q_{>0}$,
then the results satisfy
$$
\mu^*(c,S_1)=\mu^*(c,A)=\mu^*(c,S_2)
=c\left\lceil\frac{b-a}{c}\right\rceil,
$$
with the exception that it can ocassionally happen
that the value is
$c\left(\left\lfloor\frac{b-a}{c}\right\rfloor+1\right)$
instead
(this depends on the rationality of $a,b$, the value of $c$,
and is hard to make precise when this happens.
Since the difference vanishes as $c\to0$, we will not go into further detail for this special case).

Some arguments for this calculation:
Suppose that you have $m<\left\lceil\frac{b-a}{c}\right\rceil$
open intervals of length $c$.
Then the complement of the union of these intervals
contains a (nonempty) interval $I_0$.
Because the sets $S_1,A,S_2$ are dense in $[a,b]$,
there would be points in $S_1,A,S_2$ which would be in
$I_0$ and therefore not covered by the $m$ open intervals.

As a consequence, of the results for $\mu^*$, we get
$$
\mu_*(c,S_1)=\mu^*(c,A)-\mu^*(S_2)=0,
\\
\mu_*(c,S_2)=\mu^*(c,A)-\mu^*(S_1)=0,
\\
\mu_*(c,A)=\mu^*(c,A)-\mu^*(c,\emptyset)=\mu^*(c,A).
$$
Then it turns out that your set function is not well-defined
for $S_1$ and $S_2$:
We have
$$
\lim_{c\to0}\mu^*(c,S_1) 
=
\lim_{c\to0}\mu^*(c,S_2) 
= \lim_{c\to0} c\left\lceil\frac{b-a}{c}\right\rceil
= b-a,
$$
but also
$$
\lim_{c\to0}\mu_*(c,S_1) 
= \lim_{c\to0}\mu_*(c,S_2) 
= 0.
$$

**Additional questions after this answer was started**:

> When $A=[a,b]$, does my set function of $S$ equal the Lebesgue measure of $S$.

I think this is not the case.
There one can construct a set $S\subset A$ that is dense,
Lebesgue measurable and has measure zero, but unlike $\mathbb Q$ is uncountable.
Then the set function would be undefined again for this set.

> If $A=\mathbb{Q}$ could we solve $\lim_{c\to 0} \mu(c,S)$ by doing the following: Take elements of $S$ that have $n$ decimal places. Take $\lim\limits_{c\to 0}\mu$ of these elements as $n\to\infty$. If we cannot do this, how can we change my definition of $\lim\limits_{c\to 0}\mu(c,S)$ so this is possible.

If we only take $\mu(c,\cdot)$ for the elements that have at most $n$ decimal places,
then we would only take $\mu(c,F)$ for sets $F$ that are finite.
If we then take the limit $c\to0$, we get $0$, which is probably not desirable.

I am not sure how to change the definition of $\lim_{c\to0}\mu(c,S)$ to get desirable properties.
Maybe you should try Hausdorff measures. These have the nice properties that they are measures.

Comment: What about when $A=[a,b]$? If $S\subseteq [a,b]$, then does $\lim\limits_{c\to 0} \mu(c,S)$ equal the Lebesgue measure of $S$?

Comment: Another hope I had was when $A=\mathbb{Q}$ we could solve $\lim\limits_{c\to 0} \mu(c,S)$ by restricting $A$ and $S$ to decimals that end in the nth decimal place and taking of my set function of $S$.

Comment: If you are correct, then when $A=\mathbb{Q}$ my set function is still undefined but I don’t want that. I was hoping we could restrict $S$ to elements that have $n$ decimals and then take the set function. How do we change my definition?

Comment: @Arbuja I adressed some additional questions. But I think it would be better if you would ask a new question on math.stackexchange for any future new questions that do not concern my answer.

Comment: When I meant limit $S$ to $n$ decimal places, I meant remove $I_k$ intervals of length $c$ whose start-point is not in $S$ then take the measure of the remaining $I_k$ intervals. It’s like with the Lebesgue measure of the set of all numbers with a 7 in the decimal place.

Comment: What if I changed my definition of outer set function to be $\mu^{*}(S)=\left\{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_k):I_1,...,I_m \text{ has length of } 0<c\le 1, S\cap \bigcup_{k=1}^{m}I_k\right\}$ which is the infimum over all possible combinations of sub-intervals.